# Howto find the cause of excessive memory usage on w7?

Tags: windows

My new w7 box with 8Gb ram was kind.
But from a few days, it use a lot of memory : 5GB without any 
desktop application (only my firefox...).

Here is  output from tasklist + tasklist /mvc

```
firefox.exe 4008    95 692 Ko
explorer.exe    3636    72 768 Ko
MsMpEng.exe 5568    62 604 Ko
perfmon.exe 3976    43 864 Ko
sidebar.exe 2336    28 232 Ko
dwm.exe 1240    27 752 Ko
svchost.exe 1036    24 944 Ko   AeLookupSvc,BITS,Browser,EapHost,gpsvc,IKEEXT,iphlp
ruby.exe    3664    21 440 Ko
RocketDock.exe  2156    16 024 Ko
plugin-container.exe    3388    15 760 Ko
Console.exe 624 15 500 Ko
taskmgr.exe 2736    13 092 Ko
CLMLSvc.exe 4184    12 148 Ko
svchost.exe 416 11 240 Ko   Dhcp,eventlog,lmhosts,wscsvc
svchost.exe 1208    10 896 Ko   CryptSvc,Dnscache,LanmanWorkstation,NlaSvc,Wecsvc
mozystat.exe    6064    10 708 Ko
svchost.exe 5768    10 048 Ko   AudioEndpointBuilder,hidserv,Netman,PcaSvc,TrkWks,U
msseces.exe 2324    9 668 Ko
......
```

Resmon show nothing special.
Search indexer is stop, msmpeng is suspend.
So Perhaps some shared memory are attached to memroy.

How to identify where come from this excessive memory use ?

Thank you

Comment: Try http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 2):

It's disk cache, don't worry about it.

Don't think about memory being used as "excessive".  Rather, **memory that's not used is wasted**.  Disk cache makes good use of memory but leaves it available to any application that would perform allocations.

Comment: When i run a process (irb) and try to take big memory, i get

Comment: If you're getting out-of-memory errors, that's because you have a 32-bit program and ran out of address space.  If you run out of physical memory things will get slow (due to swapping) but you won't get errors.

Comment: ou are right: i create 8 process wich take 1Gb ram (jruby -J-Xmx1500m -e "str='*'*(1000*1000*1000); p str.length; sleep 15") and after 10 secs my memory is free ...

Comment: You should have said, "It's disk cache, be thankful for it." What's the point of having 8GB RAM and not using it?